# Applying complex functions on pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, scipy

I have a df of line segments, each line segment is identified by a unique id **id** and **x** and **y** coordinates.

df:

```
   id       x       y
0   1     0.1     0.2
1   1     0.6     1.2
2   1     2.2     1.6
3   1     2.3     1.9
4   2     0.4     0.9
5   2     0.8     1.5
6   2     1.5     1.7
7   2     1.7     2.3
8   2     1.8     3.0
```

I want to increase the sampling points of each segment in the df to 8 points each, and store the new points in a new df.

In the above df, points belonging to the same id is one line segment, so in the df above there are 2 line segments with id 1 and 2.

Below code shows increasing sampling points for an individual **one line segment**, say the line segment with id = 1 from the above df

```
df2 = df[df["id"]== 1]

new_x = np.linspace(df2["x"].max(), df2["x"].min(), 8)
new_y = sp.interpolate.interp1d(df2["x"], df2["y"], kind='cubic')(new_x)
```

But I want to perform this operation on the whole df above, and increase sampling points for each line segment. For this we can groupby  **groupby(["id"])** and then get new_x and new_y for each of the line segments and store it in a new_df, with columns id, new_x, new_y.

Expected df should have the line segment id and new_x and new_y columns like below

```
  id     new_x        new_y
0  1       2.3          1.9
1  1      1.98         1.17
2  1      1.67         0.94
3  1      1.35         1.03
4  1      1.04         1.19 
5  1      0.72         1.25
6  1      0.41         0.99
7  1      0.10         0.20
8  2      val          val
9  2      val          val
#Followed by 6 more rows for id 2 with new_x and new_y
```

Please let me know if anything is unclear.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Please check

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is wrong with what you're doing now?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ  I am not getting how to apply it on the whole data frame, when there are multiple line segments. Right now I did it manually, but if there will be a lot of line segments, I cant do it individually for them.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ can u please check the question again, I ve tried to make it more clear

Answer (score 1):

I think @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ can provide more efficient way , but you can try this .

```
LIST=[]
for name,df2 in df.groupby("id"):
    new_x = np.linspace(df2["x"].max(), df2["x"].min(), 8)
    new_y = interpolate.interp1d(df2["x"], df2["y"], kind='cubic')(new_x)
    New_df = pd.DataFrame({'id':name,'new_x': new_x, 'new_y': new_y})
    LIST.append(New_df)


pd.concat(LIST,axis=0).reset_index(drop=True)


Out[55]: 
    id     new_x     new_y
0    1  2.300000  1.900000
1    1  1.985714  1.170057
2    1  1.671429  0.948328
3    1  1.357143  1.027302
4    1  1.042857  1.199468
5    1  0.728571  1.257314
6    1  0.414286  0.993329
7    1  0.100000  0.200000
8    2  1.800000  3.000000
9    2  1.600000  1.905774
10   2  1.400000  1.582319
11   2  1.200000  1.498203
12   2  1.000000  1.512189
13   2  0.800000  1.500000
14   2  0.600000  1.337362
15   2  0.400000  0.900000
```

Comment: Thank you so much, but in the for statement, instead of writing **name, df2** can we write **name, df** ? wont it give the same result ?

Comment: @abcdef if df you need change your original df to some one else

Comment: @abcdef If it is work for u ,  how about accept my answer ?